# How to fix an error: 'module 'qiskit.result' has no attribute 'get_counts''

Tags: qiskit

```
execute(circuit, backend = simulator).result()
plot_histogram(result.get_counts(circuit))

Error: module 'qiskit.result' has no attribute 'get_counts'
```

Comment: Hi, do you have a minimal example of code that displays this error, for people to try running to help find where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not assign the variable `result`. Try the following:

```
result = execute(circuit, backend = simulator).result() 
plot_histogram(result.get_counts(circuit))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. I am a beginner right now that's why I was struggling!